# Many to Many relationship with unique name

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hello i am trying to do the following:

I have a user entity and a role entity. The user entity has many roles and the roles have many users. Now i want to have the role name which is a string and unique.

I've tried to set it up but get:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'ROLE_USER' for key 'UNIQ_57698A6A5E237E06'
```

I do something on preInsert on the user side, namely:

- if no user exist, find one role
- if no role exist, add default roles
- add role ROLE_USER to the user (role ROLE_USER has already an id)
- if no user exist, add ROLE_ADMIN to the user (role ROLE_ADMIN has already an id)

What it does it, tries to insert new ROLES instead of insert in USER_ROLE the new user_id and existing role_id.

#### User Entity

```php
<?php
namespace Entity;

use DateTime;


use Doctrine\ORM\Exception\ORMException;
use Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException;
use R3m\Io\Module\Core;
use R3m\Io\Module\Database;

use R3m\Io\App;
use Host\Api\Workandtravel\World\Service\Role as RoleService;
use Host\Api\Workandtravel\World\Service\User as Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\PrePersist;
use Doctrine\Orm\Mapping\PreUpdate;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use R3m\Io\Exception\ErrorException;

use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends Entity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $uuid;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $password;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
    */
    protected $refreshToken;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    protected $isActive;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isLoggedIn;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $isCreated;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $isUpdated;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $isDeleted;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Profile", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $profile;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Parameter", inversedBy="parameters")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_parameter")
     */
    protected $parameters;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)}
     * )
     */
    protected $roles;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->parameters = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUuid(): string
    {
        return $this->uuid;
    }

    public function setUuid($uuid)
    {
        $this->uuid = $uuid;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $test = password_get_info($password);
        if($test['algo'] === null){
            $password = $this->createPassword($password);
        }
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getRefreshToken(): string
    {
        return $this->refreshToken;
    }

    public function setRefreshToken($refreshToken=null)
    {
        $this->refreshToken = $refreshToken;
    }

    public function getIsActive(): int
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        if($isActive === 'true'){
            $isActive = 1;
        }
        elseif($isActive === 'false'){
            $isActive = 0;
        }
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function getIsLoggedIn(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->isLoggedIn;
    }

    public function setIsLoggedIn(DateTime $isLoggedIn=null)
    {
        $this->isLoggedIn= $isLoggedIn;
    }

    public function getIsCreated(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->isCreated;
    }

    public function setIsCreated(DateTime $isCreated)
    {
        $this->isCreated = $isCreated;
    }

    public function getIsUpdated(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->isUpdated;
    }

    public function setIsUpdated(DateTime $isUpdated)
    {
        $this->isUpdated = $isUpdated;
    }

    public function getIsDeleted(): ?DateTime
    {
        return $this->isDeleted;
    }

    public function setIsDeleted(DateTime $isDeleted=null)
    {
        $this->isDeleted = $isDeleted;
    }

    public function setProfile($profile){
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

    public function getProfile()
    {
        return $this->profile;
    }

    public function getParameters(): array
    {
        return $this->parameters->toArray();
    }

    public function addParameter(Parameter $parameter){
        $this->parameters->add($parameter);
    }

    public function hasParameter($parameter): bool
    {
        if($this->parameters->contains($parameter)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function deleteParameter(Parameter $parameter){
        $index = $this->parameters->indexOf($parameter);
        $this->parameters->remove($index);
    }

    public function deleteParameters(){
        $parameters = $this->getParameters();
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
            $this->deleteParameter($parameter);
        }
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    public function addRole(Role $role){
        if($this->hasRole($role)){
            return;
        }
        $this->roles->add($role);
        $role->addUser($this);
    }

    public function hasRole(Role $role): bool
    {
        if($this->roles->contains($role)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function deleteRole(Role $role){
        $index = $this->roles->indexOf($role);
        $this->roles->remove($index);
    }

    public function deleteRoles(){
        $roles = $this->getRoles();
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->deleteRole($role);
        }
    }

    public function createPassword($password='', $cost=13): string
    {
        return password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @throws NonUniqueResultException
     * @throws ErrorException
     * @throws OptimisticLockException;
     * @throws ORMException
     */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->setUuid(Core::uuid());
        $datetime = new DateTime();
        $this->setIsActive(0);
        $this->setIsCreated($datetime);
        $this->setIsUpdated($datetime);

        $object = App::instance();
        $entityManager = Database::entityManager($object);
        // first created user has ROLE_ADMIN
        $one = Service::findOne($object);
        if(!$one){
            // create Admin user
            $role = RoleService::findOne($object);
            if(!$role){
                //create ROLES
                RoleService::createDefault($object);
            }
            //every user gets ROLE_USER
            $role = RoleService::findOne($object, 'ROLE_USER');
            if($role){
                $this->addRole($role);
            } else {
                throw new ErrorException('Cannot find role: ROLE_USER');
            }
            $role = RoleService::findOne($object, 'ROLE_ADMIN');
            if($role){
                $this->addRole($role);
            } else {
                throw new ErrorException('Cannot find role: ROLE_ADMIN');
            }
        } else {
            //every user gets ROLE_USER
            $role = RoleService ::findOne($object, 'ROLE_USER');
            if($role){
                $this->addRole($role);
            } else {
                throw new ErrorException('Cannot find role: ROLE_USER');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->setIsUpdated(new DateTime());
    }
```

#### Role Entity

```php
<?php
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role extends Entity {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    protected $users;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getUsers(){
        return $this->users->toArray();
    }

    public function addUser(User $user){
        if($this->hasUser($user)) {
            return;
        }
        $this->users->add($user);
        $user->addRole($this);
    }

    public function hasUser(User $user){
        if($this->users->contains($user)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function deleteUser(User $user){
        $index = $this->users->indexOf($user);
        $this->users->remove($index);
    }

    public function deleteUsers(){
        $users = $this->getUsers();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $this->deleteUser($user);
        }
    }
}
```

If i remove the unique of Role name, it will be inserted but i want the role table to have unique Role names, anyone ?

Comment: So it looks like you got the persist set which is good.  You did not show the code which fetches an existing role from the database.  If you want to add say ROLE_ADMIN and you already have a ROLE_ADMIN in your database then you need to explicitly fetch the ROLE_ADMIN entity before adding it to the user.  If you simple create a ROLE_ADMIN entity locally then Doctrine will always try to create a new database entry for it.  Lots and lots and lots of question on this.

Comment: I do fetch an role entity and it has an ID,  but it still wants to add it

Comment: Can you update your question and show the fetching?  Try to keep it simple.  I just want to see the $em->fetch followed by $user->addRole portion.  Might even consider deleting most of the entity code you posted while you are at it just for clarity.

Comment: So I scrolled down a bit further to User::prePersist and that code goes off into la la land. Who knows what it is doing. So I think I'll just give you a good luck here and perhaps suggest a redesign in which you ensure you always have proper role entities without relying on the event system. Or singleton's for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a new entity manager with:

```php
$object = App::instance();        
$entityManager = Database::entityManager($object);
```

in the prePersist hook i think that was the cause it wants to insert instead of update.

my updated fixed code:

```php
 /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->setUuid(Core::uuid());
        $datetime = new DateTime();
        $this->setIsActive(0);
        $this->setIsCreated($datetime);
        $this->setIsUpdated($datetime);

        $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();

        $repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Role::class);
        $role = $repository->findOneBy(['name' => 'ROLE_USER']);
        if($role){
            $this->addRole($role);
        }
    }
```

thanks for looking at it !